# Port Forwarding from Localhost to other Server

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding

i'm very new to server, iptables etc. therefor i would appreciate if someone can help me with this:

i need to set up a port forwarding from Localhost, Port 3306 to 192.168.0.22, Port 3305

How can i implement this ?

Thank you so much.

Jan